# Hardware for Operating System development

Tags: operating-system, system

I am heavily interested in Operating System theory and design and have decided I would like to play with developing an OS. I have a background in x86 assembly and have looked into ARM also. I would like a development board to develop the OS for. Has anyone had experience with OS development and/or can suggest some hardware to use?

One board I am considering is the [LPC1769 LPCXpresso board](http://www.lpctools.com/lpc1768.lpcxpresso.aspx).

I am aware I could use a VM, but I would like to use actual hardware.

Comment: consider electronics.stackexchange.com too

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there might be another place for this type of question :)

Comment: I'd recommend getting a cheap old notebook with Pentium II/III/Celeron CPU, serial & parallel ports, Sound-blaster-compatible audio chip and a floppy drive (if it can boot from a USB flash stick, it's an extra plus). Why? Because there are a lot of tools for x86, because you'll be able to communicate with the outer world using those ports and the audio DAC/ADC, because there is a lot of sample code for programming all those devices and because you're familiar with x86.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I personally started off with an RTOS called freertos (http://www.freertos.org/). This is an open source RTOS and is very minimalistic. It is also supported across a ton of platforms and is well written and maintaned. I ran it on a PIC32 microcontroller kit. However I would recommend you try something like Arduino boards which are more suited for beginners.
Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, you have found your way by now, but I would definitely recommend the FreeRTOS + LPCXpresso 1769 combination.